# Navigation drawer scroll view issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

I am using a `recyclerview` were there is a grouping of items according to their date added (Eg. Alphabets starting with A will be under a heading Tab A.. as in the contact list ). The problem arises when i scroll down to bottom and when i come back to top the heading tab is not grouping properly.. like if you take the Eg. given above.. When i scroll down to bottom and come back to top not all the alphabets starting with A is under the head tab A.. some goes under b head tab.. there is no problem with the listing of items its proper, only with the head tabs. If anyone have came across this kind of issue.. Please do help me. Thank you.

Here is my code inside onBindViewHolder()

```
  class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder>
    {
    private List<OrderPosting> orderPostings;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
    int index,size;
    String date;
    List<String> orderCountInsideAdapter;
        List<String> storeCount = new ArrayList<>();

    public OrderAdapter(List<OrderPosting> orderPostingList, int size, List<String> orderCount, List<String> storeCount)
    {
        this.orderPostings = orderPostingList;
        this.size = size;
        this.orderCountInsideAdapter = orderCount;
        this.storeCount = storeCount;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name, store, cost, date,statusColor,orderId;
        LinearLayout linearLayout,mainLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);

            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personName);
            store = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.storeName);
            cost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalCost);
            date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateOrdered);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lastSeenLinearLayout);
            mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayoutOrderHistory1);
            statusColor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status_color);
            orderId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.order_history_items, parent, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) parent;

        return new OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            for (OrderPosting orderPosting: orderPostings)
            {

                if (Objects.equals(orderCountInsideAdapter.get(position), orderPosting.getOrderId()))
                {

                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String date1 = df.format(new Date());

                    String dateTime = orderPosting.getDateAdded();
                    index = dateTime.indexOf(" ");
                    date = dateTime.substring(0, index);
                    Log.e("DateChange addes..////", date);

                    if(Objects.equals(tempDate, date))
                    {
                        Log.e("Temp date111/////",tempDate);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("Temp date222/////",tempDate);

                        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        tempDate = date;

                        if(Objects.equals(date1, date))
                        {
                            holder.date.setText("Today");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
                            SimpleDateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");

                            try {
                                convertDate = readFormat.parse(date);
                                Log.e("Changed date",""+writeFormat.format(convertDate));
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            holder.date.setText(writeFormat.format(convertDate));
                        }
                    }                  
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return size;
    }        
}
```

So in the above code holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); is the head tab layout.. I am grouping it accordingly with the date.

Comment: Can you show some code for your adapter?

Comment: Take a look at my code i have edited above..

Comment: Can you show the entire adapter code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. i have added my whole adapter code above..

Comment: When you scroll up, your first item starting with "A" will show the header layout - am I right? If yes - you should only show the header, if the "A" item is the first of the "A" items... Though another thing - there is a more reasonable way to make grouped list, where you specify itemtypes and keep data in, maybe a grouped list - I can come up with an example if needed.

Comment: Yes please can you give me an example..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `if(Objects.equals(tempDate, date))`.
Your `tempDate` is a global variable and when you on bottom, your saved date starts with `Z` for example.

By scrolling from bottom the last value will comes first -> you set head on false item.

Comment: I have tried making tempDate from global to local variable.. not working

Answer (score -1):

Hep! Here is one grouped adapter coming up your way. Hope it helps:

https://github.com/mathiasnielsen/mathirialdesign/blob/master/MaterialGuidelines/MathirialDesign/app/src/main/java/com/example/kirkegaard/mathirialdesign/Lists/GroupedListActivity.java

.... and in case the link does not work:

```
package com.example.kirkegaard.mathirialdesign.Lists;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kirkegaard.mathirialdesign.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GroupedListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<CountriesData> countriesData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grouped_list);

        countriesData = new ArrayList<CountriesData>();

        MakeDummyData();

        SetupRecyclerView();
    }

    private void SetupRecyclerView()
    {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.grouped_reyclerview);

        GroupedAdapter adapter = new GroupedAdapter(countriesData);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void MakeDummyData()
    {
        MakeDummyDataSection("A", 10);
        MakeDummyDataSection("C", 4);
        MakeDummyDataSection("G", 13);
        MakeDummyDataSection("H", 12);
        MakeDummyDataSection("Z", 3);
    }

    private void MakeDummyDataSection(String letter, int itemsCount)
    {
        List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            cities.add(letter + (i+1));
        }

        countriesData.add(new CountriesData(letter, cities));
    }

    private class CountriesData
    {
        public CountriesData(String letter, List<String> countries)
        {
            Letter = letter;
            Countries = countries;
        }

        public String Letter;

        public List<String> Countries;
    }

    private class GroupedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        private final int HEADER_TYPE = 0;
        private final int ITEM_TYPE = 1;

        private List<CountriesData> _data;
        private List<ItemInformation> _itemTypes;

        public GroupedAdapter(List<CountriesData> data)
        {
            _data = data;
            SetItemInformation();
        }

        private void SetItemInformation()
        {
            _itemTypes = new ArrayList<ItemInformation>();
            int categorySize = _data.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < categorySize; i++)
            {
                _itemTypes.add(new ItemInformation(HEADER_TYPE, i, 0));

                for (int j = 0; j < _data.get(i).Countries.size(); j++)
                {
                    _itemTypes.add(new ItemInformation(ITEM_TYPE, i, j));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            if (viewType == HEADER_TYPE)
            {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_group_header, parent, false);
                return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
            }
            else
            {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_group_country, parent, false);
                return new CountryViewHolder(itemView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            ItemInformation info = _itemTypes.get(position);
            if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder)
            {
                // Populate header data;
                String headerText = _data.get(info.GroupIndex).Letter;
                ((HeaderViewHolder)holder).PopulateWithData(headerText);
            }
            else
            {
                // Populate item data;
                String itemText = _data.get(info.GroupIndex).Countries.get(info.InnerIndex);
                ((CountryViewHolder)holder).PopulateWithData(itemText);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)
        {
            ItemInformation info = _itemTypes.get(position);
            return info.ItemType;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {

            int itemCount = 0;

            for (CountriesData countryWithSameLetter: _data)
            {
                // For header
                itemCount ++;

                // For content
                itemCount += countryWithSameLetter.Countries.size();
            }

            return itemCount;
        }

        private class ItemInformation
        {
            public ItemInformation(int itemType, int groupIndex, int innerIndex)
            {
                ItemType = itemType;
                GroupIndex = groupIndex;
                InnerIndex = innerIndex;
            }

            public int ItemType;

            public int GroupIndex;

            public int InnerIndex;
        }
    }

    private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView headerTextView;

        public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            headerTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_header_textview);
        }

        public void PopulateWithData(String text)
        {
            headerTextView.setText(text);
        }
    }

    private class CountryViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView itemTextView;

        public CountryViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            itemTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_country_textview);
        }


        public void PopulateWithData(String text)
        {
            itemTextView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. But I can't understand the whole part. I don't know till what extent this will help..!!

Comment: Sorry if it gets to complicated - but you should be able to try it out in your own activity and test and see how it works... If it still seems like gibberish, how about the comment I wrote earlier, where you need to show the header only if the item is first item starting with an A? Will that help. Hope you will take the time to understand the adapter I provided, since I believe it is a good approach to use a grouped adapter. Cheers